# How do I prevent workspace chaining?

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two catkin workspaces. One of them where I work, and one where I just want to mess around. Unfortunately the second one extends my primary workspace. I want to have them as independent as possible. How can I have them both just extend /opt/ros/kinetic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283343/how-do-i-prevent-workspace-chaining?/) by [felixcra](https://answers.ros.org/users/33766/felixcra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-22**:
Was your edit intended to highlight a particular part of your question?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-22**:
If it's unclear how to remove the current dependency, you'll need to rebuild both your workspaces. Delete the `devel` and `build` folders and run catkin again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two options (off the top of my head):

1. don't have one sourced when you're building the other (ie: don't have `source /some/path/to/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` in your `.bashrc` (or similar file))
2. use `catkin_tools` and initialise the configuration of the respective workspaces with the `--extend` option to explicitly extend (or really: overlay) `/opt/ros/kinetic`

---

Edit: perhaps three: `source`ing a setup file should override whatever vars are already present in your environment, so if you'd `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` before building either workspace it should (implicitly) extend `/opt/ros/kinetic`. I'm not sure how reliable that is though, so personally I would probably go for option 1 or 2 (actually I do both: I have 50 workspaces and none of those are sourced automatically).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2018-02-21**:
+1 for the `catkin config --extend /opt/ros/kinetic` approach